# Update or modify Clouformation template has no effect

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm using boto3 to update the a Cloudformation stack. However, any changes I do to the template are never saved for some reason. No error is thrown and I see (in the Cloudformation events log) that the update has occurred but the template is no changed.

The change I'm trying to make is changing some script in the Metadata init section.

Here is an abbreviated version of the template

```
"Metadata": {
  "Build": {
    "Ref": "Build"
  },
  "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
    "configSets": {
      "init": [
        "init"
      ]
    },
    "init": {
      "files": {
        "/var/myapp/deploy.sh": {
          "content": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                "# I do some things here...",
                "# I want to add some changes here..."
              ]
            ]
          },
          "context": {
              "param1": {
                "Ref": "param1"
              },
              "param2": {
                "Ref": "param2"
              },
          },
          "mode": "...",
          "owner": "...",
          "group": "..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the update script

```
stack_name = 'MyStack'
updated_template_body = '...'
stack_params = [...]
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.update_stack(
    StackName=stack_name,
    TemplateBody=updated_template_body,
    Parameters=stack_params
  )
```

The response is always a `200 ok` response and no error is thrown, however no change is being done to the template.

According to [this link](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-get-template.html) the template is updatable through the CLI so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Calling `cfn-init` doesn't seem to help as the template is never changed...

Thanks,

Comment: Are you saying that when you add even a test comment then go to the console inside the Cloudformation template tab you do not see the new comment?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil it's probably pretty outdated by now and I don't entirely remember, but if memory serves, than yes.